# Can't access $_GET after rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's the mod_rewrite portion of my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

# Protects file paths
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php?route=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /mysite/index.php?route=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

When I type in `http://localhost/mysite/home` it correctly takes me to `index.php?route=home`.

When I type in `http://localhost/mysite/services/` it works again, and I can correctly access `$_GET['route']`

so for example, my menu has:

`<li<?php if($_GET['route'] == 'home') { echo ' class="selected"'; ?>>`

to set the class on that page.

**but....**

When I type in `http://localhost/mysite/services/widget`, it correctly takes me to `index.php?route=home&page=widget` but I get a PHP error if I try to reference `$_GET['page']` (or ANY `$_GET` value for that matter) ...which as I mentioned before, I was using to set the `selected` class of the menu item.

Can someone help me fix this? I must've done something wrong with the second rewriterule... because it doesn't pick up any `$_GET` values.

...

This is really strange because I use `$_GET['route']` and `$_GET['page']` to populate the correct html for the page (similar to an MVC setup)... I would've thought the `php include` I have on index.php would've failed if it couldn't find the `$_GET`

....

**Edit:**

Maybe it's relevant, but my index.php code looks like this:

```
if( isset( $_GET[ 'route' ] )) {
    if( file_exists( 'content/' . $_GET[ 'route' ] . '.php' )) {
      if( isset( $_GET[ 'page' ] )) {
        if( file_exists( 'content/' . $_GET[ 'route' ] . '/' . $_GET[ 'page'] . '.php' )) {
          include 'content/' . $_GET[ 'route' ] . '/' . $_GET[ 'page'] . '.php';
        }
      } else {
        include 'content/' . $_GET[ 'route' ] . '.php'; 
      }
    } else {
      header( "Location:404" );
      exit;
    }
  } else {
    header( "Location:home" );
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you try `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: @icktoofay - INTERESTING.... I get Array ( [route] => services/widget) ...but my page still populates properly... I also tried index.php?route=services/widget and it behaves as if page was set to widget ?? The rules are definitely conflicting with each other... the fact my html populates properly is probably a fluke. How do I combine this rewrite into 1 rule, or 2 rules that won't conflict??

Comment: You're using `.*`. `.*` will match slashes as well as other characters. Perhaps try using `[^/]*` instead; that will match anything but a slash. Since your question also mentions URLs that end with slashes, you might want to add `/?` to the end of the regular expression (before the `$` of course) as well.

Comment: @icktoofay - I'm super noob, can you give me an example with the correct syntax? also the trailing slash was unintended... but I don't mind it

Comment: As a replacement for your second rule: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /mysite/index.php?route=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Also, check the pages against a list of valid pages, rather than only using `file_exists`. Currently your code is vulnerable to a directory traversal + poisonous null byte attack.

Comment: @icktoofay - Great advice on the `file_exists`. The rewrite rule didn't change anything though... I think the issue is that I have 2 similar rules. Is there a way to do `if...then` type rule?

Comment: You replaced the first rule, too? The second one was just an example of how you'd modify the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your order of rewrite rule is a problem here. You should always have most specific rules first and then put generic ones. If you change your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteBase /mysite

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /mysite/index.php?route=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php?route=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

**And make sure you have above code in mysite/.htacess file.**

With above if you visit `http://localhost/mysite/services/widget` and do `print_r($_GET);` you will get:

```
Array
(
    [route] => services
    [page] => widget
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your rewrite rules are fighting each other; they're both set up to act on the exact same conditions. I'm no mod_rewrite expert, but that seems like a clear problem to me.

Comment: I need someone to help create a hybrid of the two then, because not all URLs will have a 2nd path to populate the "page" attribute...

Comment: I'm only a level .5 htaccess rule-writer, I can only respond to what appears to be an obvious conflict. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. If your GET vars are present in the URL PHP should be able to grab them. Try stacking your rewrites like this and see if it helps:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: The URL is visible as `localhost/mysite/services/widget` for example, so I can't SEE the GET variables, but I used them to populate the HTML... which is why I'm confused. Btw, doing what you suggested gave me an Internal Server errorr...